# Parse a JSON array with YAJL

Tags: c, arrays, json, yajl

I am trying to parse an array within a JSON file, like so

```
{
    "val": [5,6]
}
```

using the following code, adapted from the `parse_config.c` included with the library,

```
char errbuf[1024];
yajl_val node;

long length;
char *file_data = read_file(&length, "conf.json");

node = yajl_tree_parse((const char *) file_data, errbuf, sizeof(errbuf));

const char *path[] = {"val", (const char *) 0};
yajl_val v = yajl_tree_get(node, path, yajl_t_number);

if (v)
    printf("Node found.\n");
else
    printf("Can't find node %s\n", path[0]);

yajl_tree_free(node);
free(file_data);
```

This method is successful for a single value, e.g.

```
{
    "val": 5
}
```

(by successful I mean that `v` is populated and `Node found.` is printed) but not for the array. What do I need to do differently for the array to be parsed?

Thanks.

Comment: `{ "val' = 5 }` is not valid JSON.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker oops, just a mistake in typing the question. Fixed now, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

- You can use YAJL_IS_ARRAY to check v is array true or false. If v is an array,it will return true. If v is not an array, it will return false.
- Next, You can use this code to parse it:

  ```
  size_t len = v->u.array.len;
  int i;
  for ( i = 0; i < len; ++i ) {

      // get ref to one object in array at a time
      yajl_val obj = v->u.array.values[ i ]; // object
      if(YAJL_IS_DOUBLE(obj)){
              printf( "%s/%f ", key, obj->u.number.d );
      }
   }
  ```
- For details, You can see here: [Parse complex JSON sub objects in C with YAJL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716063/parse-complex-json-sub-objects-in-c-with-yajl)